# mvn test very very slow

Tags: java, maven, testing

I have ten Maven projects and for each project I have to perform a specific test case for n times (with n very large).
To run the test case I run the command 
`mvn -Dtest=className#methodName test`, but it is extremely slow. I can't modify the project pom.

Is there a faster command that works like the one written above?

I found this command https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html, but it stops at the first success of the test.

Comment: More likely that it's not maven that's slow - it's the test.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I don't think so, because the same projects if imported on intellij are executed in a few milliseconds.

Comment: I've never seen Maven to be slow when running tests. Perhaps this is your problem and you need to re-think how you're performing this test: _"I have to perform a specific test case for n times (with n very large)."_ Running the same test N times via Maven doesn't make a lot of sense unless parameters are different, in which case a parameterized test is more appropriate: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider The parameters do not change between runs. I have to run the same test n times to check if at some point there is a change in the result (flaky test).

Comment: Why should there be a change in the result? What possible source of flakiness does the test depend upon?

Comment: @JFMeier I'm doing research and I need to see if these tests have flaky behavior.

Comment: @ValeSwire are you using `Random` in a test/code under test? If you let's say create a file with predefined data and parse it and your test checks how that data in the file is parsed there is no source of flakiness here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `mvn -Dtest=className#methodName test` multiples times is not a good idea because each time, all phases before `test` are executed before actually running the test.

If you really want to run the same test multiple times, try `mvn -Dtest=className#methodName surefire:test`. But note that it would be better to dig into the tests to make sure they are deterministic instead of running each and every test a hundred times.